# How do you fix when posh~git stops working

Tags: git, powershell

I didn't do anything to my GIT configuration, not even log into github.com lately, but this morning when pushing to a branch on Windows posh~git I got the proverbial:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Would anyone know what might have caused this (if I didn't do anything and got this error)?  Maybe posh~git did something during an update?

Comment: What's the output value of `git config --get credential.helper`?

Comment: I guess smth is wrong with your pubic key. Do you get any output when running this: cat ~\.ssh\id_rsa.pub ?

Comment: Hi Mattias, I get nothing when I run that.  Mike, it does actually print out a file of the id_rsa.pub.  I think I'm going to try deleting the contents of .ssh, and redoing it with the ssh-keygen command.

Comment: Running as admin? Did you lose rights to the private key on the hard drive?